# Keep a point constant and other point moving in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Please help me on this. I have both the points 'o' and 'x' moving. I want only the 'o' to move and the 'x' to be constant.

```
% animation_point.m

clear; close all;

 % Create data
 t = 0:0.001:1;   % Time data
 x = sin(2*pi*t); % Position data
 y = cos(2*pi*t);

 % Draw initial figure
 figure(1); 
 set(gcf,'Renderer','OpenGL');
 h = plot(x(1),0,'o', 0,y(1),'x');

 set(h,'EraseMode','normal');  
 xlim([-1.5,1.5]);
 ylim([-1.5,1.5]);


 % Animation Loop
 i = 1;
 while i<=length(x)
    set(h,'xData',x(i));

    drawnow;
    i = i+1
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handle h contains both points to just update one change

```
set(h,'xData',x(i));
```

to

```
set(h(1),'xData',x(i));
```

(when testing the 'o' was the first entry)